# Can a Column in a table pick up data from Another Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table PatientChartImages. It has a column ChartImage, which contains the binary of images. Now, we are planning to create a separate table which will contain the Binary of Images and will join both the tables to get requisite data. Now, we do not want to change the front end and I cannot use triggers. So, is there any way by which if a query refers to ChartImage column of PatientChartImages, it picks data from the third table? Please suggest.

Comment: So you want anything that refers to PatientChartImages.ChartImage to automatically get data from the new table instead?

Comment: Some more info would be helpful. Is there a web service in between the client and your database? What are you using for your data access?

Comment: We are using EntityFramework 4.0

Comment: Yes I want anything that refers to PatientChartImages.ChartImage to automatically get data from the new table instead.

Comment: Are you using the EF objects directly on the client, or do you have an intermediate object that is passed around to the client?

Comment: We get EF objects and then fill our domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think **inner-join** does this. I've only overheard it's use - but this might lead you towards your answer.